# How to pass a name for convenient use of tuple?

Tags: c++, c++20

I would like to improve the code so that it is convenient to interact with it.

```
struct prototype {
  template <class... T1>
  prototype(T1&&... args) {
    auto p = std::tie(args...);

    std::cout << std::get<0>(p) << std::endl;

    if constexpr(std::tuple_size_v<decltype(p)> >= 3) {
      std::cout << std::get<2>(p) << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

int option_1 = 10;
std::string option_2 = "test2";
auto option_3 = 0.41;
std::vector<int> option_4(10);

int main() {
  prototype p1(option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4);
  prototype p2(option_1, option_2, option_3);
  prototype p3(option_1, option_2);
  prototype p4(option_1);
}
```

i would like to do so

```
std::cout << option_1 << std::endl;

if constexpr (std::tuple_size_v<decltype(p)> >= 3) {
   std::cout << option_2 << std::endl;
}
```

I don't like this option `std::get<0>(p)`

Any ideas how to replace the call to tuple?

You can also see the option on https://godbolt.org/z/bT4Wzjco8

Comment: It's unclear where the names need to come from? From `main`? Not possible. Be defined internally in your function? Sure, just do `auto &option_1 = std::get<0>(p);`.

Comment: What you need is [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's a pity you can't take the name through main.

Comment: @dyra4ek: If you could, what would happen if `main` had written `option_1+1` as an argument, or `++option_1`, or `(0,option_1)`, or even `(option_1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable template out of a lambda. At the end of the day all you want is a compile time constant to pass to `std::get`:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto option =  [] (auto p) -> auto&& { return std::get<N-1>(p); };
```

This **can** be used as `option<1>(p)`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eerne41fW)

---

The familiar template syntax for lambdas may seem as another alternative:

```cpp
constexpr auto option = []<std::size_t N>(auto p) { return std::get<N-1>(p); };
```

Here the argument to `std::get` is passed as a non type template parameter. As `@Davis Herring` mentions, this unfortunately does not mean the lambda is then to be used as `option<1>(p)`. The reason being that the lambda is not itself a template, its function call operator is. The [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf) changes nothing on the templateness of the lambda itself. As a result the lambda above is invocable as

```cpp
option.operator()<1>(p)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d5TKrxf3M)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I get <source>:8:18: error: expected '{' before 'template'
    8 | auto option =  []template<std::size_t N>(auto p) {

Comment: Remove `template`, you don't have it in your answer.

Comment: is it possible without the letters (p)?
and what if i need an array? `option_4[1]`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, correct I'm adding a link to the code

Comment: You can capture `p` in the lambda so you don't have to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to make different names for each option.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes, but then I'd have to declare it inside "prototype" I mean that's also convenient :)

Comment: @dyra4ek *"make different names"* So, just assign the result of `get` to a reference?

Comment: Can this be done?
`option[0]` 

and array call
`option[0][1]`

Comment: I get an error with triangle brackets

Comment: @dyra4ek I'd keep the combination of options simple, Before scaling to multidimensional option clusters consider making a class that holds your options instead of creating that ad hoc with variadic templates. Regarding `option[]` I guess a class with templated overloaded `operator[]` would do the trick, but you somehow have to make the "integer" template parameter deducible from an integer argument. Another solution is to make `std::get<option_1>(p)` and friends by declaring `option_1, option_2 ...` as enumerators.

Comment: @dyra4ek I also get an error when non deduced template parameters are involved. I'm going over the wording of https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf to see if I'm missing something

Comment: @dyra4ek But if options are themselves arrays, the proposed solution should work as `option<1>[1]` (get option 1, then if that is an array index it)

Comment: I can't start it yet, errors pop up.

Comment: Can you show me a working version here? 
https://godbolt.org/
no matter how I try, I can't compile

Comment: @dyra4ek https://godbolt.org/z/eerne41fW . I've also edited the answer

Comment: A generic lambda is not a template: its `operator()` is.  The syntax you (and everyone else) want has never been proposed, and most of this answer needs to be changed to not be misleading.

Comment: @DavisHerring Look at the edit. I mention that I cannot get the familiar template syntax for lambdas to be invoked with `option<1>` and I suggested storing the lambda in a variable template, which is a template. At the end there is a demo with the suggested solution working

Comment: Your lambda always returns a value, which is wrong. You should use the trailing return type, ie, `-> auto&&`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Out of curiosity, would trail returning `-> decltype(auto)` have the same effect ?

Comment: @DavisHerring Re-edited around the phrase "A generic lambda is not a template: its operator() is". That's a very nice description of the situation.